# How can I extract Text in real-time for Azure Cognitive Services?

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-search, azure-cognitive-services, azure-form-recognizer

I'm looking to build an app which performs various text based Cognitive Services functions against documents.

However, I seem to be failing at the first hurdle which is getting the text from the documents in the first place.

I'm aware that both OCR and Form Recogniser both perform variations on this ("Text Recognition" and "Text Extraction" respectively) - but for standard documents (e.g. Word / Excel / PDF) this feels like massive overkill.

Cognitive Search includes the "document cracking" process - but I need to process the documents in real-time so don't want to have to deal with Indexes in Azure.

Is there a more simple "get me the text" functionality in Azure (either in Cognitive Services or otherwise) I can use for this?

What I *don't* really want to have to do do, is have to write my own functions for each different file type (e.g. PDF / DOCX / TXT / PNG / MSG) and work out which API I need to use for each one.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I might suggest Windows Search also will not include "real time" as you have to wait for the Index

I am also expecting to run this in the cloud

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK, there's no ready to use tool besides Document Extraction from Cognitive Skill (Azure Cognitive Search):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/cognitive-search-skill-document-extraction.

You can also build your own pipeline to extract the text using Tika.NET:

https://github.com/KevM/tikaondotnet

Comment: Tika.NET looks very good.. 

Regarding the use of Cognitive Search - do you know if there is any way to process it in real time (i.e. Index and Extract immediately) or do you have to commit to a storage component and wait for the index to update?

I like the idea of Cog Search - because you can all of the other skills such as Text Analytics / LUIS and the like ..

Comment: If you are asking about stream, it's supported too: https://github.com/KevM/tikaondotnet/blob/master/src/TikaOnDotNet.Tests/stream_text_extraction.cs

Comment: I mean Cognitive Search

Comment: yes, I was talking about the tika part.

Comment: Cognitive Search does not have a realtime api for Skillsets.  Document extraction in Cognitive Services uses Tika as well so using it directly should provide the realtime capability you are looking for.